# How to use the replace string function with a path with special characters?

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a string path in a shape by replace function. I have this string:    `C:\Users\me\Desktop\p1.jpg` and I want to replace only this`C:\Users\Desktop\me\Desktop` for `'C:\Users\main\peter` and get `C:\Users\main\peter\p1.jpg`

I put this code `replace(`'C:\Users\me\Desktop','C:\Users\me\Desktop','C:\Users\main\peter')`but I get`C:?sers?ain?eter`without`p1.jpg` and with ? instead of \

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using Python.

You can use the `os` module to get the filename from your original input, then join the filename to your new path.

```
import os
os.path.join(r'C:\Users\main\peter', os.path.basename(r'C:\Users\me\Desktop\p1.jpg'))
```

Comment: Just to point out that the r in front of the string means "raw" and causes python to interpret escape characters, \, as normal characters.  So your original replace code may work just by adding r to the front of the strings.